# why state property is not displaying value from computed in VUEX project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

While building a VUE project with VUEX. I'm not getting the property from the state that is defined in 
todos.js VUEX module but getting the normal property that is defined in VUEX store. I've used modules and separated the files.

**HTML**

```
<div> isLoading: {{ isLoading }} </div>     // isLoading: 
<div> isValid: {{ isValid }} </div>         // isValid: true
```

**COMPUTED**

```
computed: {
isLoading() {
  const loading = this.$store.state.isLoading;
  console.log(loading);
  return loading;
},

isValid() {
  const valid = this.$store.state.isValid;
  console.log(valid);
  return valid;
},
```

},

**VUEX STORE**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import todos from './modules/todos';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    isValid: true,
  },
  getters: {
  },
  mutations: {
  },
  actions: {
  },
  modules: {
    todos,
  },
});
```

**todos.js**

```
const state = {
  isLoading: true,
};

export default {
  state,
};
```

***OUTPUT***

```
isLoading:
isValid: true
```

isLoading doesn't show true but isValid show true. I don't understand the behaviour and I've read the docs and couldn't find anything.

Comment: Probably because your computed path `this.$store.state.isLoading` is wrong. You should check out the knowledge about module of vuex.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the module name

```
computed: {
  isLoading() {
    const loading = this.$store.state.todos.isLoading;
    console.log(loading);
    return loading;
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use vuex helper functionalities, such as `mapState`

```
import { mapState } from "vuex";
...

computed: {
   ...mapState("/todos", ["isLoading"])
}
```

or

```
computed: {
  ...mapState({
    isLoading: state => state.todos.isLoading
  })
}
```